# Ubuntu One Sync for multiple folders in Windows, not just the Ubuntu One folder

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows, sync, directory

I may have misunderstood Ubuntu One as a service, but this is how I had pictured it. At home, I tagged a few folders with the "Sync to Ubuntu One" tick and it started uploading.
Now back at work, on Win7, I installed Ubuntu One and thought I was going to be able to tick which of the backed-up folders I could download/sync to this machine.

From what I gather after a little research is that whatever I would like to synchronize would need to be in the Ubuntu One folder? There is no way to do this outside of that?

Thanks for confirming, or informing me whether this will be introduced in the future as an option?

Thank you very much for your help on this!

bisi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we tried to explain in the [FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Windows#What%20folders%20on%20my%20computer%20can%20I%20sync%20with%20my%20personal%20cloud?), the current beta only does manual sync of the Ubuntu One folder, and not of the other folders. For the next release we will be bringing it up to par with the Ubuntu client, but for now, just that.

Comment: Thanks for this Chipaca, and apologies for missing this in the FAQ! Must have used the wrong keywords for my search ;)

Comment: But I am just wondering, this would only be for the Windows Beta then? Would the sync work on Ubuntu? Rebooting to Ubuntu ;)

Comment: Yes, it would work on Ubuntu. In 11.04 you'll be prompted as to whether you want to sync each of those folders to a computer, either when you add the computer to your account or when the folders are created on another computer. Right now, it's automatic, you always get them all (but you can use `u1sdtool` to unsubscribe manually, and you can change the default from autosubscribing to not, and then use u1sdtool to manually subscribe -- for when you have little disk space, etc.)

Comment: I confirm, it works great on Natty, but I'll wait a little longer before upgrading to Natty on all my workstations (it nearly shot my work workstation!) ;). (I am copying my workdocuments on Win7 to the UbuntuOne folder for now!)

Comment: Is this still the case, or does multifolder syncing now work? (FAQ link is dead)

Comment: Jacob: the current release supports syncing multiple folders.