# How to sync other files than the ubuntu one folder in Windows?

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu One Sync for multiple folders, not just the Ubuntu One folder.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20280/ubuntu-one-sync-for-multiple-folders-not-just-the-ubuntu-one-folder)

I'm a total newbie to ubuntu, had a smart computer guy make it so that I'm dual booting ubuntu and vista on one laptop so I can play around with ubuntu and probably eventually switch my whole hard drive over to it.  It's great so far.

I'm using ubuntu one on, well, ubuntu, and I'm running the beta on windows.  On ubuntu I totally understand how to manage it.  On windows...not so much.  So....how do I sync other folders besides my ubuntuone folder (on windows vista)?

Answer (score 1):

From the UbuntuOne for Windows [FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Windows#What%20folders%20on%20my%20computer%20can%20I%20sync%20with%20my%20personal%20cloud?):

> **What folders on my computer can I sync with my personal cloud?**
>
> All files and folders placed within the “Ubuntu One” folder will be synchronized. We will expand this functionality in the future to match the Ubuntu desktop where you can enable any folder in your home directory for sync.

Right now you can not sync any folders outside of the UbuntuOne folder on Windows, but the developers are working on it.