# Ubuntu One Windows beta: how can I set the synchronized folders?

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu One Sync for multiple folders in Windows, not just the Ubuntu One folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20280/ubuntu-one-sync-for-multiple-folders-in-windows-not-just-the-ubuntu-one-folder)

Ubuntu one on windows beta, how can I set the synchronized folders?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't. It synchronizes `My Documents\Ubuntu One`, but there is no settings for changing this or adding multiple locations.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS supports various kinds of symlinks and hardlinks, so you can always symlink the folders you want to synchronize into the UbuntuOne folder. That's what I do with my Dropbox.

Windows 7 has proper symlinks and hardlinks as well as a commandline utility called `mklink` for managing symlinks and hardlinks as well as junctions (see below).

Older versions only support *junctions* (symlinks were only added in Windows 7 or maybe Vista) which work very similar. However, they don't include a tool for creating them, but there is a gratis tool called `junction` by SysInternals.

Answer (score 0):

The beta does not allow you to choose other folders to sync or to configure the one to be used. This is a limitation we added on the Beta since it was code that we wanted to use to test if the solution was possible.

In the very near future we are going to release the real thing where you will find all the different feature you have on linux (choose the root folder via config, sync other folders, automatic syncing etc...)

If I were you I would wait until we release the new version :)