# How can I move the Ubuntu One folder to another partition on Windows?

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows, folder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu One Sync for multiple folders, not just the Ubuntu One folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20280/ubuntu-one-sync-for-multiple-folders-not-just-the-ubuntu-one-folder)

today I've installed the current release of UbuntuOne to my Windows 7 desktop, but the installer doesn't allow me to create the UbuntuOne-folder outside my profile-directory (C:\users\me).

The Problem is, that I don't host any personal data on the windows partition. All my data stored on an extra partition (D:). So I want that the UbuntuOne folder is also on that partition.

Is there any way to sync D:\UbuntuOne?

Best regards
Stefan

Comment: Hmm, okay. I thought, that this is not a beta version anymore.

And I don't want to sync other folder than the UbuntuOne folder. I want to create the UbuntuOne folder outside my windows profile home, like Dropbox maybe.


Dropbox will always create a folder called Dropbox and you can only sync what is in it, but you can choose where you put these folder. You know what I mean?

Comment: True, its not beta anymore but on the FAQ from the UbuntuOne site it will explain that you cannot select another folder for your sync files, that information is still correct. Even dropbox didn't had that option until a few months ago, the first versions did not allow you to move your sync folder or select a new one.

Comment: Okay, many thanks for this. I hope UbuntuOne will implement this function too. That would be nice :)

Comment: Indeed! I think that wont take much more time to see around ;)

Comment: The best way to ask for a feature is to go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client and report a bug and set it as a wishlist, the more people the more we will know you want the feature :)